# Get “wrong number of arguments” on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

SportsController

```
class SportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sport = Sport.all
    @events, @errors = Bapi::Inplay.all(query)
  end

  private
    def query
      params[:query, {}]
    end
end
```

Sport index.html.erb

```
 <% @sports.each do |sport| %>
   <% @events(:sport_id => sport.id).each_slice(2) do |events| %>
```

I want send each `sport.id` to `@enevts` instance variable

---

Edited : 
When send query as hash in `SportsController` its work!!

```
class SportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sport = Sport.all
    query = {:sport_id => 1} 
    @events, @errors = Bapi::Inplay.all(query)
  end

  private
    def query
      params[:query, {}]
    end
end
```

---

Index.html.erb

```
 <% @sports.each do |sport| %>
   <% @events.each_slice(2) do |events| %>
```

Comment: Which line is the error thown on?

Comment: i get error on this line `params[:query, {}] `

Answer (score 4):

`params` is a hash and method `:[]` can accept only 1 argument.

```
 def query
    params[:query] || {}  # Will return :query part or empty Hash if it has nothing
 end
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
    @events(:sport_id => sport.id).each_s... on this line  ` <% @events(:sport_id => sport.id).each_slice(2) do |events| %>`

Comment: @Gasem `@events(:sport_id => sport.id)` in your view doesn't make any sense and is incomprehensible to the Ruby interpreter either. You need to fix this, but it's separate problem, so I guess this answer should be accepted.

Comment: check this one, it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558916/loop-in-ruby-on-rails-html-erb-file