# NameError in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

So I am making an app to manage projects and its task,
using a tutorial I have made some basic stuff.

Now I want to add a timeline to my page, so I wrote this in my pr_list.rb (model file)

```
def timeline
  @pr_lists.each do |pr_list|
    pr_list.pr_items.each do |pr_item|
      if pr_item.completed?
        @timeline = "#{pr_item.descrpition}: {#{pr_item.completed_at}}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And i called it in my pr_list/views/index page.

```
<h1><%= pr_list.timeline %></h1>
```

but I get

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `pr_list' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000029fb8>
Did you mean?  @pr_lists")
```

At this point even if I just code it like to output a string, it just does not work.

if I try any other things, it gives me a `NoMethodError`

while the rest of the methods work.
and the above code also works if I write it in HTML.ERB index file as an embedded ruby.

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

Comment: You showed the **use** or `pr_list` in the template; but where is this identifier defined?

Comment: show the view, controller and model.

Answer (score 0):

**pr_list** is local to the block defined in the controller so it is not accessible from the template.

You could iterate on **@pr_lists** from within the view file (see [this question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558916/loop-in-ruby-on-rails-html-erb-file)):

```
<% @pr_lists.each do |pr_list| %>
  <% pr_list.pr_item.each do |pr_item| %>
    <% if pr_item.completed? %>
      <h2><%= pr_item.description %>: <%= pr_item.completed_at %></h2>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```